# Unhibernate Windows w/o direct access

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, partitioning, hibernate, ubuntu-14.04

I attempted to repair my boot partition with boot-repair yesterday, which worked, except that partition I have Windows 8.1 on is hibernated. As of now, I am still unable to boot my computer to anything aside from the BIOS or a disk I made with a copy of Ubuntu 14.04 to fix my computer. Is there a way to un-hibernate windows, or simply to mount it without having direct access to the OS or the files on the partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the hard drive and connect to another PC, delete the **hiberfil.sys** file on the root of the drive. You will lose any unsaved data for that session you hibernated.

You can also boot from another disk and delete it from there, something like a linux live cd or flash drive.

Windows should boot now.